Powershell script with FIleZilla Pro CLI script embedded - how to properly iterate over local and remote paths
I have a scenario where I need to ftp thousands of files from a remote server to an intermediate - the intermediate has the ftp server installed - then from there to the destination server, Due to security I cannot ftp direct from remote to destination.
I have a Powershell script for each of the 2 steps, each script creates a FileZilla Pro CLI script per subdirectory.
My 1st script works as expected, iterating over all folders and subfolders, doing a put where newer or a different size.
The 2nd script I cannot get to work, it does not seem to work out the remote(intermediate) and local paths properly, or create folders locally if not existing(where they exist on remote).
I have included only the relevant parts of each script, as an example for the 2nd script, local root would be 'F:\MyDir\Images' and on remote the root is '\Images'
1st push script - remote to intermediate:
 Add-DirectoryCommands -localPath $dirPath -remotePath $remoteDirPath -filezillaCommands ([ref]$filezillaCommands)

    # Iterate over each subfolder and file in the current directory, including nested subfolders
    Get-ChildItem -Path $dirPath -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
            # Create the directory on the remote server
            $relativePath = $_.FullName.Substring($localDirectory.Length) -replace "\\", "/"
            $remoteSubDirPath = "$remoteDirPath/$relativePath"
            Add-DirectoryCommands -localPath $_.FullName -remotePath $remoteSubDirPath -filezillaCommands ([ref]$filezillaCommands)
            $dirsCreated++
        } else {
            # Increment the files checked counter
            $filesChecked++
            $globalFilesChecked++

            # Prepare local and remote file paths
            $localFile = $_.FullName -replace "\\", "/"
            $relativePath = $_.DirectoryName.Substring($dirPath.Length) -replace "\\", "/"
            $remoteFilePath = if ($relativePath) { "$remoteDirPath/$relativePath/" + $_.Name } else { "$remoteDirPath/" + $_.Name }

            # Add file upload command
            #log-message "$localFile to $remoteFilePath"
            $filezillaCommands += "put --exists size_newer `"$localFile`" `"$remoteFilePath`""
            $filesCopied++
            $globalFilesCopied++
        }
    }

2nd get script - intermediate to destination:
Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder.FullName -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
            # Create the directory on the remote server
            $relativePath = $_.FullName.Substring($rootFolder.FullName.Length) -replace "\\", "/"
            $remoteDirPath = "./$relativePath"
            $scriptContent += "mkdir $remoteDirPath" + "`n"
        } else {
            # Increment the files checked counter
            $global:filesChecked++

            # Prepare the download command
            $localFile = $_.FullName -replace "\\", "/"
            $relativePath = $_.DirectoryName.Substring($rootFolder.FullName.Length) -replace "\\", "/"
            $remoteFilePath = if ($relativePath) { "/$relativePath/" + $_.Name } else { "/" + $_.Name }
           log-message "$relativePath -- $remoteFilePath to $localFile"
           $scriptContent += "get --exists size_newer `"$remoteFilePath`" `"$localFile`"" + "`n"
        }
    }


It probably has to do with the account and where the default destination folder is located for FTP.  You may need to do a CD to change to a folder where you have permission to write the file or change the default folder for FTP on destination for the user account.  I've been using FTP for almost 45 years and usually issues are with permissions and/or the default folder.  The only other issues I have with FTP is the default mode.  A often need to switch from Text to Binary or Reverse binary to text.  FTP is very robust and once logged in it usually works.

Without the generated script, it's hard to know what is cause.
Also, you can enable logs to debug the problem:
# enable info level logging
set engine.log.debug_level info

# note that you have to provide the full path to the file
set engine.log.file C:\\Users\\me\\fzprocli.logs
set engine.log.detailed 1

Have you considered using file synchronization? See the documentation for the sync command at https://filezillapro.com/docs/v3/filezilla-pro-cli/file-synchronization-cli/
